# VSCode latex duplicates the preview window after saving the file if the first preview window is not active

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, tex

I am using VSCode with the extension latex-workshop on Ubuntu 22.04. No other extensions for latex are installed, nothing but some snippets are modified after the fresh installation.

Suppose that I split the editor area into two windows, the left and the right. On the left, I place the .tex file, while on the right I open the latex preview.

*An annoying thing happens like this*: I usually open a second .pdf file on the right window for reference when I am typing in the left editor, which means on the right the new .pdf is an active tab and the latex preview is an inactive tab. In this case, every time I save the .tex file, VSCode pops up a new preview window above the working editor rather than directly updating the first latex preview on the right. One may frequently need to close the new preview in my situation.

I wonder if anyone has some clue about this problem? What might be the settings I need to check?